# How to completely disable built in microphone on Macbook?

Tags: audio

As a music app developer, I need to test how the app works on a Mac without any audio inputs (some Mac Minis don't have built-in mic and list line input only when there is something connected to it). To do that, I would need to make the built-in microphone invisible to apps, similar to disabling a device driver on Windows.

Note that just muting the input is not enough. Disabling microphone permission also still allows the app to see the microphone and even access it, but the app receives only silence.

Comment: You could try deleting the various audio kext (keep a copy in case you want to put them back) and rebuild kernel cache as described [here](https://www.macworld.com/article/3091124/mic-drop-how-to-keep-snoops-from-listening-to-your-laptops-microphone.html) in the *"Remove the drivers"* section.  On Catalina you'll have to do this from recovery or remount root volume rw.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this if easier solutions don't turn up. The article sounds like this might be the only way, though.